# What is the last written record from Arda?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

What is the youngest written record from Arda?

I’m not refering to the last thing that we know has happened, or what Tolkien had in mind (e.g., in Wikipedia’s [Timeline of Arda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Arda), the last entry from the [Fourth Age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Arda#Fourth_Age) is "c. 220: End of Eldarion's reign", but this seems to come from one of Tolkien’s letters), but to something *written* by inhabitants of Arda.

According to the linked timeline, a copy of the [*Red Book of Westmarch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Book_of_Westmarch) was made in year 172 of the Fourth Age. Was there *anything* (even mundane things like, say, a report on poor harvests) later?

Comment: as of the time that you asked your question, it was your question. it has now been superseded by this comment.

Comment: Given that the Thain's Book (the Gondorian transcription of the Red Book of Westmarch to which you refer) is the source of our information about Arda - that is, the in-universe source of the information which became *The Hobbit*, *The Lord of the Rings*, and *The Silmarillion* - it seems futile to ask this, since you're asking essentially "Is there anything written after The Thain's Book was finished, and included in The Thain's Book?" - that's clearly not possible.

Comment: @MattGutting: Ah, so is this book the *only* written source from Arda (that we have "access to" ;))? Didn’t know that.

Comment: Yes, essentially that's the extent of the "Frame Story" that Tolkien came up with; everything including *The Silmarillion* is, or is a novelization of, material from the Thain's Book.

Comment: @MattGutting **Including** *The Silmarillion*? Source? (If so: Mind. Blown.)

Comment: @Lexible Christopher Tolkien, in the Foreword to *The Book of Lost Tales, Part I* states: "the 'books of lore' that Bilbo gave to Frodo provided in the end the solution: they
were 'The Silmarillion'. But apart from the evidence cited
here, there is, so far as I know, no other statement on this
matter anywhere in my father's writings; and (wrongly, as I
think now) I was reluctant to step into the breach and make
definite what I only surmised."

Comment: @Lexible And "the evidence cited" is a quote from *The Lord Of The Rings*: "in the Note on the Shire Records added to the Prologue in [the second edition] my father said
that the content of 'the three large volumes bound in red
leather' was preserved in that copy of the Red Book of Westmarch which was made in Gondor by the King's Writer Findegil in the year 172 of the Fourth Age." This is what (in the frame narrative) became *The Silmarillion*.

Comment: @MattGutting Huh! Well I'll be!

Comment: There are records made by AElfwine of England that date to the late first millennium of our time and supposedly made during or after his stay on Tol Eressea.  These survived into Tolkien's post-LotR writings, such as the last version of the Akallabeth

Comment: @DarthMelkor Hm. Are we talking *History of Middle-Earth* here? *digs out HoME* I think part of the problem is the vexing "What's canon in Middle-earth?" with its annoying answer "It depends on what period of Tolkien's life you're talking about." I usually don't take *HoME* in the same sense as *The Hobbit*, *LoTR*, or *The Silmarillion* because of the high level of editorial narration involved. (Not that *The Silmarillion* didn't have a lot of editorial involvement, but it didn't push it in your face like *HoME* does.)

Comment: @MattGutting - I personally rank the non-editorial narratives and essays in HoME higher than the published Silmarillion, because they present what Tolkien actually wrote, but at the same time it must be accepted that there is a lot of contradiction in them.  They generally are a reliable source for his last thoughts on a subject, and where they are consistent with material published in Tolkien's lifetime I'd argue that they should take priority.

Comment: @DarthMelkor I see what you're saying (though I'm not certain I agree); but in this particular case I'd say that there's definite contradiction between Aelfwine's involvement in the Akallabeth, on the one hand, and the statement about the Silmarillion material coming from Bilbo's *Translations from the Elvish*.

Comment: @user8719 HoME makes much more sense when you take a "timeslice" - the _most_ complete mythology is from the 1937 Quenta Silmarillion (with gaps filled from the Quenta Noldorinwa of 1930).  To support these "Tales of the Jewels, there are some _complete_ supporting documents; the Ainulindale (creation story), the Ambarkanta (geological history), the Lhammas (note on languages), and the Later Annals (which are IMO later than the QS as they refer to Balar, and have a more complete War of Wrath story).  The way certain details are "distributed" between separate documents is an added attraction!

Answer (score 2):

The note on  the shire records in the prologue to The Fellowship of the Ring says that: "This account of the end of the Third Age is drawn mainly from the Red Book of Westmarch."

Clearly other sources beside the Red Book were claimed.  It is possible that Tolkien also consulted more than one copy of the Red Book - copies written later than the Thain's Book and not containing all of Bilbo's Translations from the Elvish but perhaps containing other versions of the main story.

Tolkien may have had oral sources as well, since he says that hobbits claim they were once much taller than they now are.

Thus Tolkien may have written down notes about events dated later than Fourth age 172, but I do not remember reading about any of those later events in Lord of the Rings.